# PHP Remove first div tag and keep the inside content

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace

I am working with php,

this is my string:

```
<div style="color:#fff;height:10px">
 <table>some code</table>
 <div>bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

I would like this output:

```
<table>some code</table>
<div>bla bla bla</div>
```

The first `<div>` tag with its attributes (style, id, etc...) and it closer `</div>` is remove from string

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp:

```
$new_html = preg_replace("/(^<div[^>]*>|<\/div>$)/i", "", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$alldetail = '<div style="color:#fff;height:10px">
 <table>some code</table>
 <div>bla bla bla</div>
</div>';

$maindetail = str_replace('<div style="color:#fff;height:10px">','',$alldetail);
$maindetail = str_replace('</div></div>','</div>',$maindetail);

echo $maindetail;
```